# Identity involving dot product of solid angle and gradient

Tags: integration

How to prove following for $n\geq0$ ?
$$\int_{4\pi}d\vec{\Omega}(\vec{\Omega}\cdot\vec{\nabla})^{2n}f(\vec{r})=\frac{4\pi}{2n+1}\nabla^{2n}f(\vec{r})$$
Where, at any point $\vec{r}$, the $\vec{\Omega}$ can be described by the polar angle $\theta$ measured with respect to the *z* axis and an azimuthal angle $\phi$ measured with respect to the *x* axis, *i.e.*
$\vec{r}=x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}+z\hat{k}$,
$\cos\theta=\vec{\Omega}\cdot\hat{k}$,
$\cos\phi=sin^{-1}\theta(\vec{\Omega}\cdot\hat{i})$
Here, $\vec{\Omega}$ is a unit vector situated at $\vec{r}$ and pointing in the direction ($\theta,\phi$) which is different than the direction of $\vec{r}$.

Comment: I will point out that the tag ([tag:geometry]) is deprecated on MathOverflow and should not be used - see [the tag-info](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/geometry/info). A tag with this name is still in use on Mathematics - where you [originally asked the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3183969/how-to-prove-this-identity-involving-dot-product-of-solid-angle-and-gradient).

Comment: Thanks @MartinSleziak for useful suggestion! This mistake was because of my unawareness being new here. I tried to remove this tag but it is asking for another one. Kindly suggest a suitable one.

Comment: You wrote that $\vec{\Omega}$ has length $1$.  In particula,r this means $$\cos^2\theta+\cos^2\phi\leq \Vert\vec{\Omega}\Vert^2= 1.$$ If e.g. $0\leq \phi.\theta<\frac{\pi}{4}$,  this is not satisfied. Does  this mean that $\vec{\Omega}$ is not defined for such angles?  What is the $\hat{j}$ component of $\vec{\Omega}$?  What does integral over $4\pi$ mean?

Comment: Respected @LiviuNicolaescu sir, thanks for pointing this out! $\phi$ is the azimuthal angle, which means that it is the angle which projection of $\vec{\Omega}$  in x−y plane makes with x-axis. And then in this case the x, y and z components of $\vec{\Omega}$  will be $sin\theta cos\phi$, $sin\theta sin\phi$ and $cos\theta$ respectively. Actually you caught an error in a published paper. This identity was mentioned (without proof) in Ann. Nuc. Ene. 20, 9 (1993) 623. While defining the problem, it wrongly mentioned as $cos\phi=(\vec{\Omega}\cdot\hat{i})$.

Comment: (continuation of previous comment on question by @LiviuNicolaescu sir) Actually it should be $cos\phi=sin^{-1}\theta(\vec{\Omega}\cdot\hat{i})$. I have corrected in the question also. Your comment is really helpful and has more insight. Therefore, I request you to keep it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of isotropy, the differential operator 
$$J_n=\int_{|\vec{\Omega}|=1} d\vec{\Omega}\,(\vec{\Omega}\cdot\vec{\nabla})^{2n}=C_n\Delta^n$$
with $\Delta$ the Laplacian. To find the coefficient $C_n$, let $J_n$ act on $z^{2n}$,
$$J_n z^{2n}=(2n)!\int_{|\vec{\Omega}|=1} d\vec{\Omega}\,\Omega_z^{2n}=2\pi(2n)!\int_0^{\pi}\sin\theta d\theta\,\cos^{2n}\theta=\frac{4\pi}{2n+1}(2n)!=C_n\Delta^n z^{2n},$$
hence $C_n=\frac{4\pi}{2n+1}$.

Comment: Respected sir, thank you so much for you answer!  By repeated application on $z^{2n}$ it is easy to get  $( \vec{\Omega} \cdot \vec{\nabla} )^{2n}$ equivalent to $\Omega_{z}^{2n} \frac{\partial^{2n}}{\partial z^{2n}}$. However, will it be correct to write in general, $(\vec{\Omega} \cdot \vec{\nabla})^{2n}$ equivalent to $\Omega^{2n} \Delta^{n}$ ? because $\Delta^{n}=( \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial y^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial z^{2}} )^n$? (My question may be very silly as I am a beginner in mathematics. If so, I apologise)

Comment: yes, the operator $J_n$ must be a scalar and it must be isotropic; that fixes the form $J_n=C_n \Delta^n$.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your prompt and explaining answer! I am enjoying learning from supportive experts (like you) across the globe through this portal.